# ruby comparing two identical strings as a condition for if else

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to use the comparison of two strings as the condition for my if else statement, but when i compare the string 'true' is printed and the script is terminated. Is there any way to use the string comparison so that the if/else statement will execute?

```
udhead = string
ddown = string

 if udhead == ddown
    puts 'User directory header pass' && $log.info("User directory header pass")
  else
    puts 'fail' && $log.info("User directory header fail")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to use `and` not `&&`:

```
puts 'User directory header pass' and $log.info("User directory header pass")
```

which evaluates `puts` and `$log.info()` separately.

The form you use evaluates like:

```
puts ('User directory header pass' && $log.info("User directory header pass"))
```

And is same as

```
puts (true)
```

I'm not sure though why you have to join two statements like that when you can just do

```
puts 'User directory header pass'
$log.info("User directory header pass")
```